# Angular JSON object break up into new line is not working

Tags: json, angular

I'm creating custom table configuration, Some lengthy header names i need to break up into new line, i tried `'\n'` and `<br>`, but it doesn't work for me.

app.component.ts

```
columnDefs = [
      {headerName: 'Make <br> Production', field: 'make', edit:true },
      {headerName: 'Model/\n\nLatest Model', field: 'model', dropdown: true },
      {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', edit:true}
  ];
```

app.component.html

```
<tr style="background:#f5f5;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of columnDefs" >
      <td>{{ item.headerName }}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
```

Is any work around for this?

[Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdydoy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[innerHTML]` property binding to interpret the HTML `<br>` tags.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of columnDefs" >
  <td [innerHTML]="item.headerName"></td>
</ng-container>
```

However, it is generally better to keep formatting logic separate from data. Therefore, CSS would be preferred to set column widths and let lines automatically wrap.

Comment: thanks i'm not aware about this property `[innerHTML]`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to put HTML tags into your model data.

Please use CSS to do the line break. You can give your table cell a max width and the browser will break it up into multiple lines if necessary.

Comment: thanks, I'm generating table dynamicly, some of the tale body content is not just a type text, it might dynamic html content.